# Python Exception Message Escaping <=> character

Tags: python, databricks

My colleagues and I are working on some code to produce SQL merge strings for users of a library we're building in Python to be run in the Azure Databricks environment. These functions provide the SQL string through a custom exception that we've written called DebugMode. The issue that we've encountered and I can't find a satisfactory answer to is why when the DebugMode string is printed do the <=> characters get removed? This can be replicated with a simpler example below where I've tossed various items into the Exception string to see what would get printed and what wouldn't.

```py
raise Exception('this is a string with the dreaded spaceship <=> < > <= >= `<=>` - = + / <random> \<rand2>')
```

This snippet results in the following:
[image: result of raised exception]

What I don't understand is why the <=> character is missing in the Exception printout at the top but is present when you expand the Exception. Is there a way to get the first string to include the <=> character?

---

I've also included the custom DebugMode class we're using.

```py
class DebugMode(Exception):
  '''
  Exception raised in the event of debug mode being enabled on any of the merge functions. It is intended to halt the merge and provide
  the SQL merge string for manual review.
  
  Attributes:
    sql_string (str): The sql merge string produced by the merge function.
    
  Methods:
    None
  '''
  def __init__(self, sql_string, message='Debug mode was enabled, the SQL operation has halted to allow manual review of the SQL string below.'):
    self.sql_string = sql_string
    self.message = message
    super().__init__(self.message) # overwrite the Exception base classe's message
    
  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.message}\n{self.sql_string}'
```

Comment: I don't know what you're viewing this in, but it seems like it may be doing some kind of bad HTML handling.

Comment: It doesn't look like this `DebugMode` thing is actually involved in the problem. You're not raising an instance of `DebugMode`.

Comment: I concur with user2357112 - this is problem with whatever is displaying the message and rendering it as HTML.  Notice that its not just the `<=>` string that is being removed, but also `<random>`, `<rand2>`, `<= ` and the `>`  in the `>=` after it.  
  If your python code is being passed to some JavaScript and being used to set a display field, maybe it's incorrectly using `innerHTML` instead of the `innerText` property.

Comment: Use `html.escape()` if you're displaying the error message on a web page, to convert the `<>` characters to HTML entities. You should do this with any plain text, especially if it's user-generated, to prevent XSS.

Comment: What tool are you using? If I use jupyter notebook the python shell, it works okay.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments folks! It hadn't even occurred to me that it might be the specific tool I was using, I should have verified with another notebook environment like Jupyter. I've edited the question to include that I'm working in the Azure Databricks environment.

I'll look into using html.escape!

To user2357112, I'm not using it in the example here since I wanted to provide the minimum required to trigger the behavior. I added my DebugMode code just in case folks saw something there that would cause this behavior.

I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just providing a follow up for anyone who runs into the same thing. This was a Databricks notebook specific issue. @user2357112 had indicated, this was a problem where Databricks was parsing the html and had reserved the notation `<some key work>` for specific purposes (you can see some of these keywords and how they're using them here: https://docs.databricks.com/error-messages/index.html).

As @tdelaney noted, this isn't an issue in Jupyter notebooks or the python shell.